# Java generics Factory Pattern with multiple Generics

Tags: java, generics, factory, abstract

I'm trying to learn how to use generics, but I am having a hard time with implementing a factory pattern. I want my DataFactory interface to have a method that returns an object of a class that extends Data. I believe the following code will work, but I'm having a hard time understanding something. Is there a way to avoid having to explicitly specify the second type in the DataFactory interface? Message extends Data<String>, so if T extends Data<U>, shouldn't the U be implied already?

Data class:

```
public abstract class Data<T> {

    private final long id;
    private final T content;
    private final User sender;
    ...
}
```

Message class:

```
public class Message extends Data<String> {
    ...
}
```

DataFactory Interface:

```
public interface DataFactory<T extends Data<U>, U> {
    T newInstance(U content, User sender);
}
```

MessageFactory Class:

```
public class MessageFactory implements DataFactory<Message, String> {

    @Override
    public Message newInstance(String content, User sender) {
        return new Message(content, sender);
    }
}
```

Why can't I just write:

```
public class MessageFactory implements DataFactory<Message>
```

I'm sorry if this is not a well worded question, I'm not exactly sure how to express it. Originally I didn't want to add type parameters to the class itself, just to the method, but I had more issues trying to make that work. I'm not even sure if I am implementing this correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because *the type system itself* doesn't know that, in the general case, you won't write `GenericData<T> extends Data<T>`. In this *specific* case, your `Message` class has a specific class for the generic type, but you could supply other parameters that wouldn't.

Comment: I understand. Other than that, is there a better way to implement what I am trying to do? Or is this implementation ok for its purpose?

Comment: @essentialz For learning purposes, you seem to be doing okay. In real-world use, I'd just use `BiFunction` and be done.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the OP selected already an answer, I want to share additional, relevant information to help others that will come here looking for answers.

## Why use generics?

First, we need to understand what is the reason to use generics in the first place. ***Generic type parameters provide a way for you to re-use the same code with different inputs***. For example, you can use generic code to handle a collection of strings, or a collection of widgets with the same code. Before generics, the way we used to handle similar cases was by casting objects. For simplification, let us use OP example and make the `Data` class non-abstract.

```
public void doSomethingWithThisInput (Object o) {
    if (o instanceof MyClass) {
        MyClass myCls = (MyClass) o;
        // do something here
    }
}
```

If you ever dealt with Java Collection before generics, you are aware of how painful this used to be. Part of the problem of the old approach was that, in many cases, you didn't discover issues with casting during development. Almost 100% of these cases were discovered at runtime which everyone can agree is very bad. With generics, these issues of object incompatibility are discovered at compile time.

## Use cases for generics

The main reason why you would want to use generics is to create a collection of similar "things" inside a class. Examples of this can be found all over the Java language with `Set`, `List`, `Map`, etc.

```
public abstract class Data<T> {
    private T content;
    // other methods and attributes omitted;
}
```

With such a class, you refer to the contents of the `Data` object generically. The data content can be literally anything: An `Email` object, a `File` object, or simply a `String`. Obviously, the intent here is that if you have a collection of data contents, each object should be of the same type. Creating a collection of disparate contents makes little sense and it is actually counterproductive.

## PECS

This is probably the most important lesson you need to learn to how to use generics properly. **PECS** is an acronym that stands for Producers Extend Consumers Super. What does this mean? The best answer I can give you can be found here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super][1]. The link is to an answer here on SO about PECS.

## Additional resource

[Oracle Java Lesson: Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: thank you for the additional info. I'm just trying to put together several things I've learned over the past couple months and figuring out how they work in conjunction. I have another class, Ledger, which holds a collection of Data Objects. In reality, I only need a Message class, but I asked myself, what if the content was something else. How could I make the code dynamic enough that the content type could be literally any object without duplicating unnecessary code. So I thought, let me try to make the main classes work with generics.

Comment: In reality this is the structure: Blockchain contains a list of Blocks, each block has a Ledger, each Ledger has a list of Data Objects.

Comment: So the idea was to make the data object content generic, and implement a concrete class for any Data Object type and a corresponding Factory. But it's causing me to refactor all my code. I'm not sure the idea was worth it. I find myself adding generic types to all the classes, and creating new classes to deal with the specific types. I need to rethink this.

Comment: I read what you posted on PECS, I'm not sure I completely understand how it applies in this situation, but I'll look into it further. Thank you again.

Comment: @essentialz you wrote "I'm not sure I completely understand how it applies in this situation" - Simple. You are creating a Factory (A producer). Therefore, according to PECS, your producer method's signature must reflect that (which it seems it does).